# ggplot() has error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `ggplot()`. The datatype of Percentage is Double. In the dataset, there is no NAs in both Percentage and Year columns.

```
l1 <- ggplot(data, aes(Year, Percentage)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="Year From 2015 to 2018") + 
  scale_y_discrete(name="Employment Outcomes")
```

The error said:

> ```
> Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) { : 
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> ```

Comment: To make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), can you edit your question to include the output from `dput(data)`? Also you haven't included any `geom_*` / `stat_*` layer. What do you intend to plot?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to specify what type of visualization you want to generate. For example, if you want to visualize time series plot, the scripts would be like this.

```
ggplot(data, aes(Year, Percentage)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Year From 2015 to 2018") + 
  scale_y_discrete(name="Employment Outcomes")
```

Basically, you need to specify `geom_*()` after `ggplot()`.
Also, another advice from me is that, use `labs()` not `scale_x_discrete()` to add names on X/Y axis.

```
ggplot(data, aes(Year, Percentage)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Year From 2015 to 2018",
       y = "Employment Outcomes")
```

This generates similar plot that you want.